# no visible global function definition and no visible binding for global variable

Tags: r, data.table, global-variables, r-package, tweets

I've installed an R package, to create retweet cascades from a tweet object json file ([here is the github page](https://github.com/behavioral-ds/evently)). Their code works with their sample data. Here is the 2 lines of code to create the cascades:

```
filepath <- system.file('extdata', 'tweets_anonymized.jsonl', package = 'evently')
cascades <- parse_raw_tweets_to_cascades(filepath, progress = F)
```

**Note-1:** the `parse_raw_tweets_to_cascades` function (in `tweet.R` file) create cascades from a given tweet object jsonl file.

**PROBLEM:** When I run it with my data (which seems to have the same structure), it correctly extract info (e.g., tweet_id, retweet_id, user_id, etc.) from data, but it doesn't create the cascades and shows this error:

> Error in rep(1:nrow(index), cascade_sizes) : invalid 'times' argument

Apparently this error happens when the second argument (`cascade_sizes`) is either negative or Null or a vector of variables. I tried to print the cascade_size using
`print(paste("Mona Cascade sizes is", cascade_sizes))` which returns the following:

> "Mona Cascade size is"

**Note-2:** After a specific line in this file (`processed_tweets <- data.table::as.data.table(data.table::rbindlist(processed_tweets_batch))`), I see the following issues:

- **no visible global function definition** for functions: fwrite, :=, and setorder
- **no visible binding for global variables** for variables: tweet_time, absolute_time, start_ind, and end_ind

I've read may similar posts, including the followings, but I couldn't fix my error yet:

- [how to use utils::globalVariables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251801/how-to-use-utilsglobalvariables)
- [ggplot2 inside R packages: Notes during CRAN tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774258/ggplot2-inside-r-packages-notes-during-cran-tests)
- [How can I handle R CMD check "no visible binding for global variable" notes when my ggplot2 syntax is sensible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439256/how-can-i-handle-r-cmd-check-no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-notes-when)

### UPDATE-1:

For example, I added the following in the tweet.R file (which was suggested in several answers):

```
#' @import utils 
utils::globalVariables(c("absolute_time", "start_ind", "end_ind"))
```

but I still get the same error.

### UPDATE-2:

I also set those variables to NULL (as suggested [here](https://nathaneastwood.github.io/2019/08/18/no-visible-binding-for-global-variable/), but still I get the same error. I added the following line to the top of my function:

```
tweet_time <- end_ind <- start_ind <- absolute_time <- NULL
```

Comment: can you provide some of your data so we can replicate the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar problems recently. The following things helped:

- I added `. <- var1 <- var2 <- NULL` to my function. The trailing point is missing in your example.
- I added `#' @import data.table` to the roxygen skeleton of my function and execute `document()`. This way the NAMESPACE file gets updated and data.table gets properly imported.